# Minimum number of calls to be made?

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

There are 'n' number of detectives..each one knows an information, how many minimum calls should they make so all the detectives know all the n number of information ?

**My answer:** I came up with 2n-3 (that is, n-1 + n-2) solution where a detective calls n-1 other detectives and shares information mutually (in this way the last detective and the first has all the information). Then the remaining n-2 detectives who doesn't have the whole data calls either the first detective or the last to gain the remaining information.

(This is a question asked by my friend).

Comment: @ Vaughn Cato >> yeah i mean it is 2n-3, as already mentioned in my answer(sorry for the writing, if you did not understand it). I'am wondering is there any optimal algorithm or some method through which we can reduce the number of calls.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood the parentheses.  I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Questions is unclear to me. Do detectives tell each other only their own secret in a call or all secrets they know.

Comment: @goldenmean >> they tell all the secrets they know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2n-3 is not correct.

Consider the case of n=4, 2n-3 would predict that 2*4-3=5 calls are needed.

However, we can do it in 4 calls via:

```
A calls B
C calls D
A calls C
B calls D
```

Comment: Proof that 2n-4 is optimal in ["R. Bumby, A Problem with Telephones"](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~bumby/telephone.pdf)

Comment: Can you briefly give an overview how the paper goes, or may be point out some other sources which can explain this paper?